A Word For A Native Born Person Who Is Ethnically Foreign
I am looking for a word or phrase to describe someone who is born in a country or place, but is ethnically not a native of that place, isn't accepted as a genuine local native in society, and may not even be a citizen of that place in countries that do not give people citizenship based upon the place of their birth.
These individuals aren't "expatriates", who would generally be born abroad and often living in a place only temporarily.
Some of these people would be "second generation immigrants", but conceivably someone could be a third or later generation immigrant and could still be viewed and treated this way, and many second generation immigrants would be assimilated, particularly if they had one native born parent and one immigrant parent.
Some countries have terms for people with this place in society who are from a particular ethnic group in a particular country (e.g. Koreans in Japan), but those words don't cover the general concept.

So, the cultural identity of this unassimilated generation remains that of their parents and grandparents? Or are they in some transitional stage?

I don't think there's a general term for this in English. We use terms that are specific to the place of origin, e.g. Italian-American for an American whose family came from Italy. But the term doesn't distinguish the immigrants from their descendants.

@TimR Not so much a transitional stage as not accepted by ethnic majority locals as part of the people associated with the country, even if the native born ethnically different person is, for example, fully fluent in the local language. Image a blond, blue eyed ethnically Swedish person who was born in and lived their whole life in Uganda, for example, if local culture rejects them as a true "native."

"Non-ethnical native" seems to take into account the race difference.

@LPH Has anyone ever actually used that term?

Part of the problem is that most English-speaking countries are more ethnically heterogeneous than some others. America as a "melting pot" is familiar, and even the UK is fairly diverse, and other former colonies have indigenous populations. "Ethnically native" is either a non-functional concept in these countries, or a highly contentious and problematic one.

@AndyBonner I was thinking that perhaps such terms may have developed among academics who study such things globally.

The closest I can imagine is that scholars surveying a culture that contains this concept might use the terminology that the culture uses. That could be non-English, or it could include the language of racial supremacists that think a country should be linked to an ethnicity. Such viewpoints can be studied, but I have trouble imagining the academic world writing from such a viewpoint.

"Pat Spratt, an American of Eastern European heritage, ..." The Wall Street Journal yesterday had a front page article, saying something like "Mexico's new president Claudia Scheinman, whose Jewish parents fled Germany before WWII.."

They are outsiders, in the view of bigots.

@ohwilleke I don't think so, I had a check on Google Books with no results. There  might be, however, certain possibilities in use with a slightly different form: "non-ethnic *" ("non-ethnic Chinese, non-ethnic Russian").

The question might be taken at a very local level, e.g. John (aged 40) was born in X village but he is still regarded as a newcomer by the other inhabitants. This suggests the paradoxical-sounding phrase "locally-born newcomer".

@ohwilleke Is there always a racial element to this dynamic?

It's one thing to be of a different ethnic group from the norm, quite another to be born there but not have citizenship; and I'd imagine whether you're accepted is going to vary from person to person. Are they trying to integrate or not? Also, by "ethnic group" do you mean race, religion? Would a white Briton in Germany count? Descendants of migrants is sometimes used, but doesn't indicate a different ethnic group.

@TimR Not necessarily, although usually to some extent that might seem subtle to outsiders (the tyranny of small differences). It might apply, for example, to a Polish person in Norway, who an American would not see as racially different, but a Swedish person might.

I believe that in Britain you would have people saying a person is British as long as they were born and raised in the UK. This naturally includes people whose families emigrated from Asia, India and Africa. (Indians are from Asia but in the UK they are considered a separate group mainly for historical reasons)

Taking it straight from the question, I think native-born foreigner is as close as you can get - there is no single word for it. The country-specific forms like “French-born Japanese” are commonly used.
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68917/16829
The concept itself might need some explanation for people from countries where it doesn’t make much sense (e.g., the US), but anyone who understands the concept should see how the term accurately describes it.
Here is a video by a person who describes herself as a “foreigner born and raised in Japan” (日本で生まれ育った外国人)
https://youtu.be/hlqAmqHG1-w?si=y-kbr3sVixk-w4jc

You acknowledge that there are countries where this term 'doesn’t make much sense', but can you be more specific as to where it is actually used? It may also be useful to clarify whether, at the places where it is actually used, it is is purely descriptive.

There is just one hit on Google for "he is a native born foreigner". Yes, you would have a difficult time convincing people that someone born and raised in a country is still a foreigner. Maybe that kind of narrow-thinking exists in other cultures but it doesn't exist in the UK nor in Italy.

It seems to me that the video, which is in Japanese with Japanese subtitles, proves people who do not physically look like Japanese even if they were born and raised in that country, will never be fully accepted or integrated into their culture.

After the edit it has become clear that, as one may have suspected, this is not a term that is standardly used in any English-speaking country. Its only use in English seems to be as the translation of a Japanese term.

native-born foreigner? That is a total oxymoron.

Such people can be described as "of X [ethnic] origin" where X can be a nationality or ethnicity.
the website "Statistics Canada" gives

Ethnic origin refers to the ethnic or cultural origins of the person's ancestors. An ancestor is usually more distant than a grandparent.
and later
Ethnic or cultural origin refers to the ethnic or cultural origins of the person's ancestors. Ancestors may have Indigenous origins, or origins that refer to different countries, or other origins that may not refer to different countries.

Thus, for example, a child born in the UK of Nigerian parents is ethnically Nigerian, or more precisely "Yoruba", if their ancestors were from that tribe.

In the US they would be referred to as "Nigerian American"

@DJClayworth Not more simply, African-American or West Africans?

Could be, if they weren't being specific. But "African American" is often just a euphemism for "Black".

Would someone who was a 2nd or 3rd generation American, even identify themselves in a census as Nigerian American? What if only one parent was born in Nigeria would that adult born and raised in the US identify themself as Nigerian American? I doubt it. I don't hear or read about people whose parents or grandparents emigrated from Japan identifying as Japanese-American, but as Asian or Asian-American.

@Mari-LouA  The categories listed on forms aren't as nuanced as the reality.Plenty of Japanese-Americans have thought of themselves as Japanese and not the  wider "Asian"; there are different Japanese words for first-generation, second-generation, third-generation immigrant from Japan.

Being of such-and-such ethnic origin is, as the quoted definition makes clear, a much wider concept than the OP has in mind. A person may have origins in another county, in that the person's seven  generations removed ancestors came from that country, but have no real connection with that country's culture, and barely be able to find it on the map. The question is about those who themselves belong to the culture of another country, not those whose ancestors belonged to it.

But a what of X origin? Is a person born in Japan to two parents who have no Japanese ethnicity (let’s say they are Swedish) or citizenship and is not herself a Japanese citizen (because neither of the parents are) a “Japanese person of Swedish ethnicity”?

The question is asking for a generic term which does not specify any "X".
